# Normalization till 3NF

Tags: database, normalization, 3nf

I tried to normalized some unnormalized data but im really not sure if what im doing is right. im still a learner. just started few months back please help.

The unnormalized set of data are 
customer[custno,cust_name,cust_addr,cust_phone(artist_id,artist_name,art_title,pur_date,price)]

This is what i ended up with

Customer [custno, cust_name, cust_addr]

Cust_contact[custno,cust_phone]

Artist [artist_id,artist_name]

Art [art_id,artist_id,art_title]

Sales [inv_num,art_id , custno,pur_date, price]

Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your unnormalized schema definition. Could you post the SQL statements that would create such table(s)?

Comment: The problem is the question came that way and i dont understand the brackets inside the square brackets.. sorry

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes. You introduced inv_num. At the conceptual level, normalization happens *after* you decide what you're going to store in your database. Also, normalization through BCNF is determined by functional dependencies. Not just *determined*, but determined with mathematical precision. So edit your question, and paste your functional dependencies.

Comment: What reference are you using for "normalization" and "unnormalized data"? Give links and/or quotes. Relations have standard notions & notations. Non-relations don't. Except "normalization to "1NF" depends on the author/textbook. So how do you expect us to interpret your assignment? Also show your work.

Comment: The nested parentheses are not standard. Guessing by the names chosen you are missing a comma after cust_phone & I'm not going to guess beyond that. Until you find out from your reference(s), notes and/or instructor(s) what the notation means and what the correct assignment is, you & we are just pointlessly guessing.